# UWP - How to show TimePicker / DatePicker in Open format on Page Load

Tags: datepicker, win-universal-app, timepicker, uwp-xaml

I am developing UWP (Win10 - VS2015) app. when the app runs, the timepicker/datepicker is always in this format, See Img (1), and when we tap on the img(1) control then it shows/popup the img(2) flyout, but I need to show the full page flyout mode (like img(2)) on Page Load, rather than tap on the img(1).

I checked the Style and Template of Timepicker but didn't find anything. Plz help.

[image]

OR how can we get the custom timepicker control same like the iPad one.
See the [img Link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Art/date_picker_2x.png)

Comment: Not sure whether it works. Try this on page load FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout( sender as FrameworkElement ); where sender us TimePicker element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround i found below solution. Hope it helps.

Attach `TimePickerFlyout` to `TimePicker`.It has got `Placement` property. There you can specify `Full mode`.

```
<TimePicker x:Name="TestTimePicker" ClockIdentifier="24HourClock" Time="0" >
                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <TimePickerFlyout Placement="Full" TimePicked="TimePickerFlyout_TimePicked"/>
                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        </TimePicker>
```

On page load showthe flyout. DOnt forget to call `UpdateLayout` of page or else Flyout wont be closed when you tap on Accept button.

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(TestTimePicker);
            UpdateLayout();
        }
```

In TimePicked event assign selected time to `TimePicker`

```
private void TimePickerFlyout_TimePicked(TimePickerFlyout sender, TimePickedEventArgs args)
        {
            TestTimePicker.Time = sender.Time;
        }
```

Here is the screenshoot. If you want to increase the width and height you can edit the style of `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter`

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much, it solved 80% of my prob, rest I will manage InshaAllah. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hello, how can I get the time in this format (4:00 PM or 9:34 AM) in TestTimePicker.Time = sender.Time, I can get the value without PM/AM via this TestTimePicker.Time = sender.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm"), but I need the actual format  as I mentioned. Plz.

Comment: plz check my this question/post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043765/uwp-how-to-format-time-in-timepicker-timechanged-select-time-without-buttons-i

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [TimePicker from Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp/time-picker)

Or you can try to edit style for standart UWP TimePicker. It's located in file generic.xaml which should be inside folder like

C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic

You can serch for TimePicker or TimePickerFlyoutPresenter

Comment: I need actually, how to show this popup when the app runs rather than tapping on the control and then show the flyout of Timepicker. Your link has the older view of the Timepicker and my one has the latest view ... but the problem is as I mentioned, how to open it directly when the App loaded.

Comment: You have image with standart UWP control, but I give you option to use another one control from syncfusion. Thats 2 different controls, they are not old and new versions.

Comment: OK good. Is this a separate library, what is this syncfusion. How to use its controls. I will use it and then will let you know.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately you can only try trial